# WF email to user that adds a document to a library

Tags: workflow

I want to include the user that adds a document to a library on an existing WF email that sends to a group email box but cannot determine how to grab the current users email addy....I'm sure it is something real simple that I'm just not seeing.

Answer (score 1):

Just simply add the Created By field into the email To or CC line, Sharepoint automatically knows who the users email address and will send an email to him/her.

Comment: Yea, apparently our system adds a bunch of system stuff to that field.  It has |*\ then a couple of digits before a user name.